# Disable Export feature in OpenERP 7

Tags: odoo

I need to disable the feature to export partners to CSV or XLS in OpenERP 7.

As I read, this can be done by changing permissions to ir.export.linea and ir.export for a group of users. But what happens is that by giving the 'Export' button actually opens the alert window saying that user don't have permission, but if the user closes this alert, behind is the fully accessible and functional export window!

Any way to disable or hide the menu 'export'?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could tweak the css to hide it - bit of a hack, but its the simplest solution.

Comment: which "more" menu are you asking about?

Comment: In Openerp 7, the 'More' menu at the top (the new place for Actions) in List View, when you have at least one row selected.
I.E.: http://www.ursainfosystems.com/uploads/1/2/6/4/12648302/7071388_orig.png?1

Answer (score 0):

In version 7 you can easily stop the export functionality of OpenERP. Just go to Settings - Configuration - General Settings and uncheck the Allow users to import data from CSV files

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I had tried that but it only hides the 'Import' button. 
'Export' remains as a submenu from 'More' button in list view.